# How to check if payment is successful on server side in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe payment but finding some problem to check if payment is successful or not at the server side.

If payment is successful then I want to trigger the database to update the payment for the user.

I am using nodejs for this integration with vue and my nodejs  code looks like this:

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
const {
 amount,
 product,
 currency
} = req.body;
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
payment_method_types: ["card"],
line_items: [
  {
    price_data: {
      currency: currency,
      product_data: {
        name: product,
      },
      unit_amount: amount,
    },
    quantity: 1,
  },
],
mode: "payment",
success_url: "http://localhost:3000/successPayment",
cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
});
res.json({ id: session.id });
});
```

Is there any way to check at server side whether the payment was successful or not? And is it safe to check it here or I have trigger the database once the user reaches the success page?

Comment: you should use Stripe Webhook: [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, webhooks are the best way to do this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#create-event-handler